# Dynamically set tabs title by JSON Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON that retrieve me the date of Yesterday, Today and Tomorrow and i have a swipe menu with three tabs, what i want his that the title of three tabs it is Yesterday's date for the first and go on..

I've already parse JSON and retrieve the data, now i need to find a way for "export" this data in the setupviewpager and set the title 
Maybe i need to modify the GetPageTitle?

Thanks for help

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String Yesterday  = "";
    String Today = "";
    String Tomorrow = "";
    //url per il recupero del JSON
    private static String url = "there is an url here";

    private ListView TodayMenu;

    ArrayList<String> DATEJSON = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DATA;

    ViewPager viewer;
    TabLayout tabsgtv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbargtv = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbargtv);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbargtv);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewer = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        //setupViewPager(viewer);

        tabsgtv = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsgtv);


        tabsgtv.setupWithViewPager(viewer);


        TodayMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todayMenu);

        new GetData().execute();

        setupViewPager(viewer);

    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Mostro avviso
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attendi..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        public class Date{
            private String yesterday;
            private String today;
            private String tomorrow;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            //faccio una richiesta al server e attendo risposta
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); 
            Log.e("RAW-JSON: ","Retrieve RAW-Json is "+jsonStr);



            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Coming here??", "Check 1");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String DATESTRING = jsonObj.getString("date");

                    JSONObject DATE = new JSONObject(DATESTRING); //Log.d("STAMPA","DATESTRING"+DATESTRING);

                    //Log.d("PER FAVORE","IERI ERA "+Ieri);
                    //ESTRAGGO E INSERISCO DOVE MI SERVE
                    Yesterday = DATE.getString("ieri");
                    Today = DATE.getString("oggi");
                    Tomorrow = DATE.getString("domani");


                    Log.e("Coming here??", "Check 2 values are -" + Yesterday  + Today + Tomorrow);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("ERRORE", "PANICO NERO");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Errore codifica dati",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });


                }
            }else{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Errore recupero dati",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //tolgo il caricamento di pDialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new YesterdayFragment(),"");
        adapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(),"");
        adapter.addFragment(new TomorrowFragment(),"");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {//TODO FORSE QUI
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate i've already read that question but don't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save these values in array list.

```
                    Yesterday = DATE.getString("ieri");
                    Today = DATE.getString("oggi");
                    Tomorrow = DATE.getString("domani");
 //for e.g. arrayList.add(Yesterday); & same for Today and tomorrow

                    Log.e("Coming here??", "Check 2 values are -" + Yesterday  + Today + Tomorrow);
```

After saving just use for loop and get the position of tab and set the value.

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
tab.setText("title");
```

Comment: Ok i'll try thank's for now

Comment: But the setupviewpager don't override and change with "" character?